# control + enter in browser takes only .com?

Tags: firefox, browser, javascript

I have this strange problem, how exactly does control + enter decides the domain of a website??
If i type stackoverflow,then hit control+enter, it works and takes to homepage, but i type ubuntuforums, 
then hit control + enter, it does not recognise its ubuntuforums.org, but goes to ubuntuforums.com??

How does this exactly work? If i need to change this behaviour, how should i do it?

Comment: Chrome usually displays the right URL in the search bar when typing. Use Arrow down + enter, and you have the same result as Ctrl+Enter.

Answer (score 4):

It just take what all you typed in the address bar, append it with `.com` and start talking to that server.

If you want to visit `.net` user `shift + enter`

If you want to visit `.org` user `control + shift + enter`

Answer (score 2):

The browsers simply add a ".com" to the end if the single word domain can't be resolved.

It is the most common TLD, and there are no smarts about it.

As for changing this behavior - it is hard coded, so nothing easy can be done.

Comment: As said by user22644, you can press ctrl+enter to add .com, Shift+enter to add .net and ctrl+shift+enter to add .org.
Plus, the "default" suffix, which is added when the domain name can't be resolved can be tunned by modifing values browser.fixup.alternate.* in about:config

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is the shortcut to add ".com/" to the end, and "http://www." to the start of whatever you've typed. For .org, the shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>